When were Allegories first introduced?
I’m doing some bibliographic work for my PhD and I’m struggling to find the earliest resources on Allegories.
They were surely made famous by the 90s book “Categories, Allegories” by Freyd and Scedrov. As of now, the nLab page does not provide many other resources.
One of the earliest mentions I found is a one liner, merely stating their invention attributed to Freyd, in the 1977 Handbook on Mathematical Logic collected by Jon Barwise. The reference given is a preprint simply titled “Allegories” to be published by the Montreal group in 1973. The other two Freyd’s works in the bibliography are his PhD thesis and his book on Abelian Categories.
Problem is, I have not succeeded so far in retrieving a copy of this paper, and all of the other papers citing I found it are posterior to 1977 and indeed cite it along the Handbook.
I have to admit I’m not familiar with Scedrov’s work (independent from Freyd) and thus I have not thoroughly checked if Allegories where introduced by himself prior to that.
Concretely, my questions are: can I, and if so how do I, access the paper (or preprint) “Allegories” by Peter J. Freyd ? What are some useful references for the early results about Allegories ?

My impression is not that allegories were made famous by "Categories, Allegories", but rather that this is the first published account of allegories. I cannot find anything to suggest otherwise in the literature.

Did you try emailing Andre Scedrov? He seems the most likely to have a copy of the notes if they still exist.

@varkor Pam Freyd mentioned you. I said that you have a knowledge of the history of category theory that is out of proportion to your age.  I rarely met Scedrov, if at all, but look forward to hearing what you can find out from him. My guess is that Allegories were Freyd's idea, but I hadn't heard of them before the book.

To underline @varkor's "impression", it is quite likely that Peter Freyd had the idea of allegories in 1973 but didn't work out their details until he write the book with Andre Scedrov. Papers often take decades to gestate. Athletic young researchers don't appreciate this, but greybeards know it only too well.

You may already know more of this history than anyone else who is currently active.
Peter Freyd has stopped using email, but I copied your question to his wife Pam. Unfortunately, she replied that they don't have this manuscript amongst Peter's papers.
She passed the question on to Michael Barr, who has given me permission to quote his reply:

There was of course a Montreal group informally, but we just held seminars sometimes sponsored a meeting,
but never published anything. And, oh yes, we did have an official centre for a few years. Curiously, we
have been trying to track down for several months a set of lecture notes by Bill Lawvere that Marta [Bunge] referred
in some paper. They were supposedly based on lectures he gave at Laval U. And published by them. They have
no record of them; Marta's papers have been trashed (apparently at her request) and we have not had an
answer from Danilo as to whether Bill [Lawvere] had a copy. Things disappear if not curated.

So, I am sorry, this manuscript does not seem to be available.

That's why it is so important to publish them, folks.
